# Derivation of Raychaudhuri equation - Trace

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, trace

In Wald  (Wald: General Relativity on page 218, equation 9.2.10) is stated that $$v^c∇_cB_{ab}=−B^c_bB_{ac}+R^d_{cba}v^cv_d $$ and to continue in order for the equation to be derived one needs to take the trace of this equation. How can I do that? What is the trace of the right part of the expression?

Comment: The trace of the RHS will be the Ricci tensor with two indices contracted with two v's, and $-B^{ab}B_{ba}$.

Answer (score 0):

The trace of

$$−B^c_bB_{ac}+R^d_{cba}v^cv_d $$
is simply the contraction on its free indices a,b.
The contracted Riemann gives the ricci tensor while for $B_{ab}$ use eq. (9.2.9) on page 217

The result is eq. (9.2.11)

Comment: I am confused on how to take the contracted result of $B_{ab}$. I have a term which contains $\frac{1}{9} \theta^2$ and cross terms of $\sigma$ and $\omega$ which I cannot rule out.